# Django: how to check if a field has been modified by the user?

Tags: python, django

I have a model in models.py; like this:

```py
class Profile(models.Model):
    user   = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='static/images/account/avatar', default='/static/images/default-avatar.png')
    bio    = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '@' + self.user.username
```

in views.py i want to check if a filed (i mean **avatar**) from Profile model has changed or not
in views.py:

```
def editProfile(request):
    user = request.user.profile
    form = AuthorForm(instance=user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if ...:
            os.remove(request.user.profile.avatar.path)
        form = AuthorForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('dashboard')
    context = {'form': form}
    
    return render(request, 'account/edit.html', context)
```

**In fact, I want the default image (or any other photo) not to be deleted if the user does not change the avatar field.**

Comment: `avatar in form.changed_data`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fields that change are listed in the [**`.changed_data`** attribute [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.changed_data). You thus can check if the avatar has changed with:

```
if 'avatar' in form.changed_data:
    os.remove(request.user.profile.avatar.path)
```